# Coldfusion MX 7 + Tomcat + OS X 10.6

Tags: tomcat, coldfusion

I'm trying to form an unholy alliance between Coldfusion MX 7, Tomcat, and OS X 10.6. (Really, I'm just trying to get CF7 running on 10.6, and Tomcat seems to be the best way to go about).

I've got CF7 and Tomcat going just fine- I can access the CF7 admin panel and set up my data sources. The problem is getting CF7 to parse code that's not in the same directory as coldfusion. Tomcat just serves up my files like they're text.

Note: Can't use a different version of coldfusion, but I can use whatever server will work.

More info:
http://localhost:8080/cfusion/example.com/index.cfm - parsed by coldfusion.
http://example.com:8080/index.cfm - same file, not parsed by coldfusion.

This is in my server.xml file:

```
<Host name="example.com" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
<Context docBase="/Applications/tomcat/webapps/cfusion/example.com" path=""/>
</Host>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mappings between file types (*.cfm) and the servlet that processes them are described in the web.xml file. web.xml should be in your WEB-INF directory, located in your context root. Since you've defined your web root as your CF context root, the WEB-INF directory should be in '../example.com'. Can you check that you have a WEB-INF directory there?

Comment: There is no WEB-INF directory in the tomcat/webapps/cfusion/example.com folder. There is a WEB-INF folder in /webapps/cfusion. Copying that same folder into example.com and restarting tomcat didn't work.

If you manage to help me with this, I will forever be in your debt!

Comment: You didn't answer my question, but I'm giving you the credit for leading me to the answer! I needed the CFIDE and the WEB-INF from my coldfusion deploy. Copied those over to /example.com and now I'm up and running!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you have configure or not host file for domain example.com.

Please see below url to modify host file.
http://decoding.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/how-to-edit-the-hosts-file-in-mac-os-x-leopard/

Comment: I'm afraid I already did that. Tomcat is serving me the requested file when I go to example.com:8080/index.cfm- it's just not parsed by coldfusion.